# помогите решить задачу со словарем

Tags: python, словари, методы

Переменные countries соединяют ряд стран с тремя крупнейшими городами каждой страны. Программе на вход будет поступать название города в переменную city. И ваша задача найти какой стране принадлежит введенный город. Если страна успешно найдена, необходимо вывести сообщение:

```
    countries = {
        "Sweden": ["Stockholm", "Göteborg", "Malmö"],
        "Norway": ["Oslo", "Bergen", "Trondheim"],
        "England": ["London", "Birmingham", "Manchester"],
        "Germany": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Munich"],
        "France": ["Paris", "Marseille", "Toulouse"]
    }
    
    city = input()
    for city in countries:
        if city == countries[1]:
            print(f 'INFO: {city} is a city in {countries}')
        else:
            print(f 'ERROR: Country for {city} not found')
```

Comment: Переменные countries соединяют ряд стран с тремя крупнейшими городами каждой страны. 

Программе на вход будет поступать название города в переменную city. И ваша задача найти какой стране принадлежит введенный город. Если страна успешно найдена, необходимо вывести сообщение:

Comment: вы вопрос переделайте - не надо дополнение в виде комментариев добавлять, пусть вопрос будет целевым

Answer (score 1):

```
countries = {
    "Sweden": ["Stockholm", "Göteborg", "Malmö"],
    "Norway": ["Oslo", "Bergen", "Trondheim"],
    "England": ["London", "Birmingham", "Manchester"],
    "Germany": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Munich"],
    "France": ["Paris", "Marseille", "Toulouse"]
}

city = input()
for country, cities in countries.items():
    if city in cities:
        print(f'INFO: {city} is a city in {country}')
        break
else:
    print(f'ERROR: Country for {city} not found')
```

Comment: Не работает! Всегда выдаёт `ERROR`!

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)